# KaustubhPatange's ImageLoaderView is always dark grey. How to change it background and shimmer color?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, shimmer

I've tried to use [KaustubhPatange's ImageLoaderView](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/ImageLoaderView) but faced with a impossibility to change colors. Yes, there aren't any instructions and explanations.

I've set various overlay parameters but there was not any changes.

Comment: Raise an issue on his repo. Go to his profile, try to obtain his email id or some other id, and mail him.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.